# Unusual Device Name In Windows Authentication Logs - JCIFS

Tags: windows, domain-controller

I've seen a few articles with similar host names, however, I can not seem to find a definitive cause.

We have seen some Windows security logs (from DC) linked to the lockout of an account; the host was not our usual format, but was in the following format:

JCIFS0_11_5C

Has anyone seen these, and could possibly shed light?

The user was connected in through VPN, so wondering if that caused issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JCIFS is a JAVA Linux component for connecting to Windows assets, via SMB(Samba).

If you are seeing that coming from a lockout event, it is most likely an issue in which some Linux system (appliance?) is configured to authenticate/authorize using a certain credential that most likely had a password change.
Some process was configured to do so at some point.

I am not very familiar with JCIFS but i have seen exactly the same issue you have, and also noticed the machine name comes in with JCIFS followed by numbers, in my case the numbers were 9_10_80. After extensive troubleshooting found the issue to be a RedHat system with the IP X.X.9.10 was causing the lockouts by attempting to use an account that had a password reset. So the 9_10 seems to have been the last two octets in my case.